# Code to use tab bar controller in iphone

Tags: iphone

i m new to iphone programming. can anybody tell me Code to use tab bar controller in iphone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: actually i did not get the right code for tab bar controller.

Comment: Read the following document [link text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

http://icodeblog.com/2008/09/28/uitabbar-iphone-tutorial/

This one explains it better:
http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2010/07/how-can-i-add-tabs-programmatically-to-uitabbar/

Comment: can u tell me how to add tab bar item dynamically.

Comment: You should have rather typed this in Google to get a result. Like this: http://davidbits.blogspot.com/2009/09/iphone-create-uitabbarcontroller.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have one more question i want to make tab bar scrollable but there is a concept of more button not scrollable tab bar can u tell me how to make tab bar scrollable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read Apple's [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation? How about the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)?

These documents will provide you with a *very good* overview of UIKit in general and the specifics of the UITabBarController, and will provide links to sample projects/code.

Until you've read and understood these, you might want to hold off on your current "stream of consciousness" approach to asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have one more question i want to make tab bar scrollable but there is a concept of more button not scrollable tab bar can u tell me how to make tab bar scrollable.

Comment: @user578194 You'll need to implement your own custom toolbar if that's the case - Apple's UITabBarController only offers the "more" button behaviour.